# Publish to Google Play through command line

Tags: android, ant, google-play, command-line-tool

Is there any option to publish Android Application to Google Play using command line tool ? I have signed my application but I can't use web browser to publish it.

Comment: AFAIK you can't. You have to use the Google Developer Console to release your application.

Comment: Why can't you use a Web browser to publish your app?

Comment: Because this process should be managed automatically.

Comment: If you ever find a suitable solution, I'd love to hear about it. Looking for same thing. My current project is a template for "many" apps. Updating manually will be painful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) and its [supply](https://github.com/fastlane/supply) tool, or a Jenkins CI server with [Google Play Android Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Google+Play+Android+Publisher+Plugin) for example.

You could also make use of the API (Google Play Developer Console > Settings > API access) and implement your own solution.

Answer (score 4):

There's also some npm packages that do it.
The one I found to work is [apkup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apkup)